# Changing texture depending on action

Tags: libgdx, preferences

So when a user makes a purchase they get a new texture available that will replace the original one. I´ve sort of pulled it of. But I also want the user to ba able to replace back to the original one if the wish to do so.

At the moment the user makes a purchase and the texture changes fine. But as I store that change in preferences it makes it permanent. So when I try to press the button to change to the original stone, which simply calls "setStone(...)" , nothing happends.

Anyone that can see where I´ve gone wrong?
P.S the code is not copied straight of, just cut in the important parts.

```
ObjectMap<Integer, Texture> screenMap = new ObjectMap<Integer, Texture>();
ObjectMap<String, Boolean> mTexturesStatus = new ObjectMap<String, Boolean>();

public void setStone1() {
    stoneImage = new Image(screenMap.get(0));

}

public void setStone(int screenId) {
    stoneImage = new Image(screenMap.get(screenId));

  }


screenMap.put(0, sdStone);
    screenMap.put(1, stone_3);


mTexturesStatus.put("stone1", stone1);
    mTexturesStatus.put("stone2", stone2);

btnArrow.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {


                    game.setScreen(0);


                    //Saves the entered text.

                    Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("preferences");
                    prefs.putString("textField", textField.getText());
                    prefs.putString("textArea", textArea.getText());
                    prefs.getBoolean("stoneOne");
                    prefs.getBoolean("stoneTwo");
                    prefs.flush(); 

                }


            });
    //screenMap.put(prefs.getInteger("stoneOne", 0), sdStone);
    //screenMap.put(prefs.getInteger("stoneTwo", 1), stone_3);
            setStone1();
            if(stone1 = true) {
                setStone(0);
                prefs.putBoolean("stoneOne", true);

            }
            if(stone2 = true) {
                setStone(1);
                prefs.putBoolean("stoneTwo", true);
            }



}
```

Comment: There are a few points in your code that are a bit odd - you call `prefs.getBoolean("stoneOne");`, but you don't do anything with it. Also your `if(stone1 = true)` should be `if(stone1 == true)`, or better still just `if(stone1)`. And perhaps when you set one of your stones to true in your map you should also consider setting the others to false to avoid confusion?

Comment: Yes I´ve changed to (stone1) just. Saw that mistake. What I don´t understand is what I should do with the prefs.getBoolean("stoneOne"); ? Do I need to "put" it aswell? Cause I tried that and it didn´t work as expected.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do with the value? `getBoolean()` just tells you if the associated value in your preferences is true or false

Comment: I want to store wether or not the boolean is true or false. Because when a user makes a purchase the boolean turns true and to prevent the users purchase to be waste when he restarts the app I want to store that purchase.